# Python 3.6: problems with changing service when connecting to Oracle 11 Database (cx_Oracle module)

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

i have some problems in changing database service through cx_Oracle module.

It seems that somehow the first connection "persists", even if delete the object or create a new connection in a child process. So, when I attempt to make a connection to another service, it raises a "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

I use a wallet to arrange connection.

```
  class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self,oracle_user,instance=os.environ["ORACLESRV"],env=os.environ["ENVPURPOSE"]):
        self.oracle_user = oracle_user
        self.instance = instance
        self.env = env

        wallet_path = "$SCRIPTS/oracle/wallets/{env}/{oracle_user}".format(env=self.env.upper(),oracle_user=self.oracle_user.upper())
        os.environ["TNS_ADMIN"] = os.path.expandvars(wallet_path)
        os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "Italian_Italy.UTF8"
        self.connection = cx_Oracle.connect("/@"+self.instance.upper())
```

The first connection is made without errors, but when I try to change service (i.e. the "instance" argument of Connection class) the connection is refused. Parameters are passed correctly to the constructor, but it's like the script keeps seeing the first wallet, which obviously contains user/pwd for the other service.

How can I overcome this "persistence"?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle reads its environment variables -- including ones like TNS_ADMIN and NLS_LANG -- only once. Once a connection has been established, the environment variables are not consulted again. This is likely the source of the "persistence" that you are seeing. You'll need to make sure that the environment variables are all defined before the connection is made and are suitable for all of the connections you intend to make; otherwise, you'll need to use a child process of some sort (but not created using a fork).